# Regarding Taking Layered Navigation In Menu

Tags: magento

Can you please tell me what to do to take all category's layered navigation when we hover over them....like sub categories come. Don't worry I have the mechanism like when we hover over any category then box comes under it....but I need each categories layered navigation under their respective box.

I mean I want a code that accepts category id & based on that it should give that category's layered navigation as it can be seen in left side of category page ex :-

```
http://118.127.41.79/~wlwholes/winelovers/index.php/red.html
```

But remember this should come not only in category page but it should be in every page :)

I tried by writing the following code in my static block :-
    {{block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"}}
for Red category & it worked but only in category page means in red.html page.

Please remember I have static block to write code or else I can also create a file & can put into static block.

If anyone still not getting what I am saying then please let me know.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Hi Anyone there who can assist me?

Comment: Hi Anyone there who can guide me?